# Android SurfaceView strange behavior

Tags: android, surfaceview

```
if(pauseGame){
    if(update){
        update = false;
        My_static_draw();
    }else{
        try {
           Thread.sleep(160);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}else{
   My_Game_draw(); //its load CPU
}
```

When I do `pauseGame = true;` it's `work(load CPU ~0%)` , but I see something strange on the display changing two(or more) image , image 1 drawn in the `My_static_draw()` , and some few last image in the `My_Game_draw();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're calling `Surface.lockCanvas()` before calling into the code included in your answer.  If you do that, you have to redraw the entire dirty region (which, by default, is the entire screen).

You're cycling through previous frames because SurfaceView is double- or triple-buffered.  If you lock and unlock without drawing anything, you're just re-submitting a previously-drawn buffer.

You can fix this by not calling `lockCanvas()`/`unlockCanvasAndPost()` at all if you have nothing to draw.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted".